# Second monitor not working through Hdmi over Cat6 extender

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, extended-desktop

Im trying to connect to my second monitor to my PC using a hdmi to Cat6 extender. The solution consists of a transmitter and receiver unit, which are connected together with a Cat6 cable. Each end is then connected to the PC and TV with a hdmi cable. The plan is to have this screen in a different room than my PC.

When connecting everything, my OS picks up the screen as a 3D monitor. However, the screen remains in standby mode even tho it is visible in the display manager. It is almost like the OS sees the device, are unable to communicate with it.

Both hdmi cables have been tested and found to work. The cat6 cable has been swapped out with a known working cable. Changing the resolution / refresh rate resulted in no improvement.

I am on ArchLinux with Gnome display manager but have tried it also on a Windows 7 laptop with the same unsuccessful result. Here are some info from xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3360 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1440x900+1920+180 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
    1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.00    50.04  
    1680x1050     59.95  
    1600x1200     60.00  
    1440x900      74.98*   59.89  
    1360x768      60.02  
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
    1280x960      60.00  
    1280x800      59.81  
    1280x720      59.94    50.00  
    1152x864      75.00  
    1024x768      75.03  
    800x600       75.00    60.32  
    720x576       50.00    50.08  
    720x480       59.94    60.05  
    640x480       59.94    59.93  
 HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
    1680x1050     59.95  
    1600x900      60.00  
    1440x900      59.89  
    1366x768      59.79  
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
    1280x800      59.81  
    1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
    1152x864      75.00  
    1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
    800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
    720x576       50.00    50.08  
    720x480       59.94    60.05  
    640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
 DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

My Xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 343.36  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-09)  Mon Dec  1 16:46:59 PST 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Tech Concepts 3DTV"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 760"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 760"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Any ideas on what I can try to get this working? Please let me know if i can provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the situation with support personnel it turns out the receiver unit may be broken. Will update the question if this turns out not to be true.